# Add key to an object in an array without mutating original variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how to add an element to an object without mutating the original variable.

For instance, this is what I have:

```js
let orders = [];
const order = { name: "John", phone: "+12345" };

if (orders.length === 0) {
  orders = [{ ...order, invoice: "INV-1" }];
} else {
  let temp;
  temp = parseInt(orders[orders.length - 1].invoice.replace(/INV-/, ""));
  orders = [...orders, order];
  orders[orders.length - 1].invoice = `INV-${temp+1}`;
};

console.log(order)
console.log(orders);
```

I notice for the first condition it works as I don't see the variable "order" being mutated when orders is an empty array. However, if for example, now orders is equal to the following:

```
let orders = [{name: "Maria", phone:"+19876", invoice:"INV-1"}];
```

I can see it goes through the "else" statement and the operation in there adds the new key to orders, however, the variable order is mutated as well.

My question is, e.g. how can I add INV-2 in this specific example without mutating order?

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but why don't you use `Array#push` since you're changing `orders` anyway?

Comment: `orders[orders.length-1].invoice` naturally mutates the order object you just added

Comment: Would there be any difference? Maybe performance related push is better? Just curious.

Comment: `orders = [...orders, {...order, invoice: \`INV-${temp+1}\`}];`

Comment: @Ferre_Diego `push` would definitely be faster as you don't have to copy the entire array for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread syntax to create a copy in the same way as in the first case.

```js
let orders = [];
const order = {
    name: "John",
    phone: "+12345",
};
function addOrder() {
  if (orders.length === 0) {
      orders = [{...order, invoice: "INV-1"}];
  } else {
      const temp = +orders[orders.length-1].invoice.replace(/INV-/, "");
      orders = [...orders, {...order, invoice: `INV-${temp+1}`}];
  }
}
addOrder();
addOrder();
console.log(orders);
console.log(order);
```